# Exchange Server - Cannot receive external emails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I have running exchange server....every thing was going fine, however last two days I cannot receive any external emails from outside the network, while I can send/receive internally and send to external address too....

when I tried to send email from gmail I got the following error:

> Delivery to the following recipient has been delayed:
>
> ```
>  ***@***
> ```
>
> Message will be retried for 1 more day(s)
>
> Technical details of temporary failure: DNS Error: Address resolution
>   of *****.dyndns.org. failed: Domain name not found

And the message never received...

Telnet output:

> 220 MAIL.****.** Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Sun, 8 Mar 2015 09:31:16 +0400

Answer (score 3):

Did you read the error message?

```
Address resolution of *****.dyndns.org. failed: Domain name not found
```

The DNS entry for your host does not exist. Log into your DynDNS account and fix it.